# Python 3.x Mostrar dados digitados em um Entry em um Label apenas depois de pressionar um botão

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label

Eu queria saber o seguinte;
No meu programa, há:
**Entry1** -> onde o usuário digita alguma informação
**btn1** -> onde ele confirma o nome e o dado digitado previamente é exibido no console
**lbl2** -> Onde o dado digitado no **Entry1** é exibido.

Porém, conforme o usuário vai digitando no **Entry1**, essa informação já vai sendo exibida no **lbl2**. Eu queria exibir a informação no **lbl2** apenas quando o usuário clicar no **btn1**, assim, mostrando que o nome foi confirmado.

Vamos ao código:

```
from tkinter import *

# Componentes da Janela
janela = Tk()
janela.title("EmagreciPet")
janela.geometry('300x500')
janela.resizable(False, False)

# Variáveis
var = StringVar()
varChoose = StringVar()
# Funções Botão
def pegar_nome():
    content = var.get()
    print(content)
# Nome do Pet
lbl1 = Label(janela, text="Nome do seu pet: ")
lbl1.pack(anchor=NW)
# Digita o nome do Pet
Entry1 = Entry(janela, bd = 2, textvariable = var)
Entry1.pack(anchor=SW)
Entry1.get()
# Botão para confirmar nome do Pet
btn1 = Button(janela, text='Confirmar nome', command=pegar_nome)
btn1.place(x=135, y=17)
# Caixa de seleção Sexo Macho
rBtn1 = Radiobutton(janela, text='Macho', variable=varChoose, value=1)
rBtn1.pack(anchor = W)
rBtn1.select()
# Caixa de seleção Sexo Fêmea
rBtn2 = Radiobutton(janela, text='Femea', variable=varChoose, value=2)
rBtn2.pack(anchor = W)
# Nome do pet digitado na tela
lbl2 = Label(janela, text="", textvariable=var)
lbl2.pack(anchor=NW)


# Fim do programa
janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui.
Basta aplicar na def:

```
def pegar_nome():
    content = var.get()
    print(content)
    lbl2.config(text=content)
```

lbl2.config(text=content)

e então, mudar

```
lbl2 = Label(janela, text="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alterando minimamente, o que você precisa fazer é mudar esta parte:

```
# Nome do pet digitado na tela
lbl2 = Label(janela, text="")
lbl2.pack(anchor=NW)
```

Note que, se você remover a parte do textvariable, o texto irá aparecer apenas após o botão ser pressionado.
E algumas pequenas alterações na função que você definiu, basta adicionar algo semelhante a este código após o print:

```
lbl2.config(text=content)
```